# Inject JS error when loading HTTPS page on Chromium

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, https, chromium

I've set up a Django app on an HTTPS server. When I navigate Chromium to https://mybrowser.com, I see this error in the console of the browser's developer mode.

```
Error
    at Client.handleResponse (inject.js:62278)
    at inject.js:62216
    at EventImpl.dispatchToListener (VM818 extensions::event_bindings:403)
    at Event.publicClassPrototype.(/about/anonymous function) [as dispatchToListener] (extensions::utils:138:26)
    at EventImpl.dispatch_ (VM818 extensions::event_bindings:387)
    at EventImpl.dispatch (VM818 extensions::event_bindings:409)
    at Event.publicClassPrototype.(/about/anonymous function) [as dispatch] (extensions::utils:138:26)
    at dispatchOnMessage (VM825 extensions::messaging:392)
(anonymous) @ inject.js:33540
Promise.catch (async)
DetectorService.detectFeeds @ inject.js:33539
(anonymous) @ inject.js:61210
MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ inject.js:25966
MergeMapSubscriber._next @ inject.js:25956
Subscriber.next @ inject.js:4702
FilterSubscriber._next @ inject.js:27077
Subscriber.next @ inject.js:4702
Subject.next @ inject.js:5370
BehaviorSubject.next @ inject.js:29231
(anonymous) @ inject.js:62357
```

Some of the JavaScript on my page will not work in those browsers. **EDIT**: This does not appear to be the case. The web site appears to work, but still has the error in console for Chromium.

But the page is free of errors when loaded in Opera or Safari. What does this error mean? What caused it? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was caused by a Chromium extension. I disabled it. The error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether all your third-party libraries also use the `https` protocol. Since if you use the protocol `https`, then it blocks all scripts that are loaded unsafe (i.e., via `http`)

Comment: Every `<script>` and `<link>` tag in my project uses `https`.